# How to aggregate the large date of status change

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

My problem is counting the number of computer which take specific status for each time from the data recording the status changes of each computer.

I have the following csv file which records when the computer status was changed.

```
machine_id, status_id, time
1,10,2010-05-01 00:00:02 # the status of the machine 1 is changed to 10 at 05-01 00:00:02
2,3,2010-05-01 00:00:04
...
```

The total number of machines is more than 50,000 and the record size is around 5 million. The number of status is about 10

I need to get the number of the computers taking each status for each time period. Say, the result file is like the following:

```
time,status_id,number_of_computers
2010-05-01 00:00:00,1,12 # the number of computer whose status is 1 is 12 from 05-01 00:00:00 to 05-01 00:15:00
2010-05-01 00:00:00,2,23
...
2010-05-01 00:15:00,1,21
2010-05-01 00:15:00,2,32
...
```

I usually use python pandas for this kind of task, but maybe the data is too large.

Which tool is suitable for this kind of task? For example, python pandas, MySQL, or Java? I would appreciate if you add sample code to achieve this task with recommended tool.